# Mysql query with and conditions

Tags: mysql

I've two tables,

table 1

```
userid  filter
thiru   1
thiru   2
thiru   3
raja    1
raja    2
```

table 2

```
headline    filter1 filter2
test          1       3
test2         1       2
```

If I want to select the users applicable for filters.
when i select test - thiru is applicable ( filter1 and filter2 ) matching
when i select test2 - thiru and raja are applicable ( filter1 and filter2 ) matching.

Basically the filters are with and condition.

Here is the query that i tried:

```
select userid 
  from table1 
 where filter in (select filter1 
                    from table2 
                   where headline = 'test') 
   and filter in (select filter2 
                    from table2 
                   where headline = 'test');
```

Please give me the query for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the query you've tried so far.

Comment: select userid from table1 where filter in (select filter1 from table2 where headline = 'test') and filter in (select filter2 from table2 where headline = 'test');
This is not working. returning empty set.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired results for your both filters by using following approach

```
select a.userid
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.filter = b.filter1 
left join table2 b1 on a.filter = b1.filter2
group by a.userid
having sum(b.headline = 'test')
and sum(b1.headline = 'test')
```

[demo(test)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8bf23/13) , [demo(test2)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8bf23/12)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you're looking to join the two tables together on the filter in table1 being either = to filter1 or = filter2, and you only want usernames that appear twice in the joined list. This is what the group by does => afte rthe tables are joined together, it groups up the number of times the username appears. Then the HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 excludes all usernames that only appear once (i.e. only matched one of the filter1 or filter2)

```
SELECT
  userid
FROM
  table1 t1
  INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
  ON
    t1.filter=t2.filter1 OR
    t1.filter=t2.filter2
WHERE
  t2.headline = 'test'
GROUP BY
  userid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Your own query was actually almost working, but it has a fatal flaw:

You wrote WHERE filter in (something) AND filter in (somethingelse). A number 1 is never = to 1 AND 3 at the same time, so there is no one row whose filter can be 1 AND 3 simultaneously.. There are DIFFERENT rows that can match this, but for that your query would need to be:

```
select userid from table1 
where 
  filter in (select filter1 from table2 where headline = 'test') OR
  filter in (select filter2 from table2 where headline = 'test')
```

I only changed the AND to OR.. This would return two rows for THIRU and one row for RAJA, so we would still need to group it up and count them:

```
select userid from table1 
where 
  filter in (select filter1 from table2 where headline = 'test') OR
  filter in (select filter2 from table2 where headline = 'test')
GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Soo.. you were close, you just need to think about things as row by row

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and here is what worked:

```
SELECT userid FROM table1 
WHERE (filter IN (SELECT filter1 FROM table2 WHERE headline = 'test') 
OR filter IN (SELECT filter2 FROM table2 WHERE headline = 'test'));
```

Adding a 'OR' between two queries worked.

Comment: You just need to add or condition after your first filter clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below structure to get the result

```
select a.userid
 from table1 a 
 join table2 b on (a.filter = b.filter1 or a.filter = b.filter2)
 where b.headline = 'test'
 group by a.userid
```